# rigid bodies: passive vs not-dynamic

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have read at different times in different tutes instructions for creating a floor, backstop, or other "scenery" object in a rigid body world;  some say "create object, add rigid body physics, then turn off Dynamic,"  while other say "create object etc, then change Active to Passive."  I have tried both, and for a simple floor I've seen little difference.  BUT...

recently I was building the Wrecking Ball demo from blenderguru, and out of habit I made the floor by turning off Dynamic, which has worked for me before.  it all worked fine until I *changed* the floor (by extruding one edge into a backstop);  then all of a sudden, cubes started falling right through it.  I could not figure it out, could not figure it out, much headbanging, then finally changed it to Dynamic+Passive rather than !Dynamic+Active (in other words, followed BG's instructions properly!).  then everything worked perfectly.

so, can someone enlighten me as to the -- subtle? -- diff between an RB object that is Not Dynamic but Active, and one that is Dynamic but Passive?  I'm guessing that the latter is the *correct* way to make immovable scenery objects.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70743/what-is-the-difference-between-passive-and-non-dynamic-rigid-bodies

Comment: I happily abandon my version of the question and will follow yours, which is better written than mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between passive and non-dynamic rigid bodies?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70743/what-is-the-difference-between-passive-and-non-dynamic-rigid-bodies)